# How do I implement nested global filters in an Ember app?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, filter, ember-data

Thanks for any help you can provide on this situation...

I'm trying to build functionality similar to Amazon's filter sidebar. When one filter of a category is selected, the other filter categories get filtered, in addition to the main content.

Let's say I'm building a store that sells `shirts` and `pants`. These can be filtered by both `color` and `size`.

`ShopRoute` loads the models for both `color` and `size`.

Routes:
`/shop/shirts`
`/shop/pants`

```
+---------------------------------------+
| Shop                                  |
| +-----------+ +---------------------+ |
| | Filters   | |   {{outlet}}        | |
| |   Color   | |     (/shirts        | |
| |     blue  | |        or           | |
| |     red   | |      /pants)        | |
| |     green | |                     | |
| |   Size    | |                     | |
| |     S     | |                     | |
| |     M     | |                     | |
| |     L     | |                     | |
| +-----------+ |                     | |
|               |                     | |
|               |                     | |
|               +---------------------+ |
+---------------------------------------+
```

The filters on the side are radio-buttons; i.e. only one `color` can be selected at a time, and only one `size` can be selected at a time.

Let's say I'm at `/shop/shirts` and I select `green`. Currently, of the `x` number of shirts available in green, the only sizes available are `M` and `L`. The `sizes` should be filtered and `S` should no longer be a selectable option.

If I have selected `green` while on `/shop/shirts`, then when I visit `/shop/pants`, the filter should persist and I should only see green pants. If all sizes are available, `S` should reappear as a selectable option.

**To be clear:** this should also work vice-versa. If a `size` is selected before selecting a `color`, the `colors` should be filtered to reflect the availability of `colors` in that `size`.

So far, my `ShopController` starts off like this:

```
App.ShopController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(
  colorFilter: null
  sizeFilter: null
)
```

I've found plenty of simple 'Hello World' filtering examples. Now, I'm mostly having trouble with the architecture of the solution, getting lost in  Ember's entities (`Model`, `Route`, `Controller`, `View`, ...) and how they interact.

How do I filter all displayed records of `color`, `size`, `shirt`, and `pants` from this controller (or elsewhere) whenever any of these options are set/reset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the Controllers with [need](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/). I would suggest creating two controllers

First one will manage the Filters / Side bar. Its property change when user select any filter in the side bar

```
App.SideBarController = Ember.Controller.extend(
  selectedColor: ['Green','Blue'],
  selectedSize: ['XL'],
)
```

Now second will be regular List controller lets say ShopListing. Here you can refer Sidebar filter with Live binding using something like this.

**binding updates in this controller automatically as you change them in Sidebar controller (via some filter selection / deselection)**

```
    App.ShopListingController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

      needs : ['SideBar'],

      //side bar live bound property for selected colors
      selectedColor : Ember.computed.alias('controllers.SiderBar.selectedColor'),

       //side bar live bound property for selected size
      selectedSize : Ember.computed.alias('controllers.SiderBar.selectedSize'),

      //write some code here to get only filtered result
      filteredListing : Ember.computed('model.@each','selectedSize','selectedColor',function(){
  //do some magic here
      })

    })
```

Hope it gives you some help :)

Also have a look on [Bindings](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/bindings/)